# Standard language for comments asking for an improved question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

One of the first things I needed to learn when coming to SO for the first time was how to ask a good question. I suspect I'm not alone in this. I was fortunate to have responses to my first (poorly asked) questions that:

1. Explained why asking the question well was important
2. Explained the steps I could take to improve my question

And they did so in an insistent but friendly way. This positive reinforcement (combined with the requirement that I do more work) allowed me to learn how to ask better questions without getting discouraged. I often think that the bad reputation that SO has among many people is that their first experience(s) asking questions were treated rudely or just downvoted with no explanation.

So I'm wondering if we should have some standard language people can use for some common question faux pas. I was prompted to ask by [Iakov Davydov](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/users/191/iakov-davydov)'s response to [this question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/162/anion-silica-membrane-matrix-compositions), which I think is a good start. Friendly but clear on what additional steps should be taken.

So the actual question: should we have a bank of standard responses? This might increase the chances that (a) people will comment to explain to people how questions can be improved and that (b) those responses will be welcoming to new users while training them to ask better questions.

Comment: Where / in what form would a bank of standard responses be stored?

Comment: Relevant userscript: [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se), which automatically stores 'canned comments' that you can customise. I find it immensely useful on Stack Overflow to provide quick guidance and save some time.

Comment: @bli right here, probably, as an answer to this very question. Other sites on the SE network have similar posts. Here's one from [ubuntu.se]: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1323/85695

Comment: I think this is a very good idea but maybe we should not expect an answer so soon. Let's see what kind of questions we get and figure out what type of information is most often missing.

Comment: Link to your question post is broken.